# How to check if a Binary tree is full?

Tags: python, binary-tree

Student here. I have coded a method to add to a BinaryTree class that checks to see if the binary tree is full (the rest of the class code came from a Python textbook). I believe it is working as it should but am new to coding and I do not know how to check without the visual of the tree to see if all of the leaves are on the same level. Can anyone take a look at the is isFullBinaryTree(self) method is correct? It is near the end of the class. The test program seems to be working, but I am not positive.

My thought was that if I coded a count variable for each side of the tree and if the count is the same on both sides, then the leaves must all be on the same level which would make it a full tree.

Here is the full code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.element = e
        self.left = None # Point to the left node, default None
        self.right = None # Point to the right node, default None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    # Insert element e into the binary search tree
    # Return True if the element is inserted successfully
    def insert(self, e):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = self.createNewNode(e)  # Create a new root/Create the node for e as the root
        else:
            # Locate the parent node
            parent = None
            current = self.root
            while current != None:
                if e < current.element:
                    parent = current  # Keep the parent
                    current = current.left  # Go left
                elif e > current.element:
                    parent = current  # Keep the parent
                    current = current.right  # Go right
                else:
                    return False  # Duplicate node not inserted

            # Create a new node for e and attach it to parent
            if e < parent.element:
                parent.left = self.createNewNode(e)
            else:
                parent.right = self.createNewNode(e)
                self.size += 1  # Increase tree size

            return True  # Element inserted

    # Create a new TreeNode for element e
    def createNewNode(self, e):
        return TreeNode(e)

    # Returns true if the tree is a full binary tree
    def isFullBinaryTree(self):
        current = self.root  # Start from the root

        while current != None:
            leftNode = current.left
            rightNode = current.right
            leftCount = 0
            rightCount = 0
            while leftNode != None:
                current = leftNode
                leftNode = current.left
                leftCount += 1  # add 1 because we are moving from current one time
            while rightNode != None:
                current = rightNode
                rightNode = current.right
                rightCount += 1  # add 1 because we are moving from current one time

            if leftCount == rightCount:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return False



def main():


    numbers = [2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 0]
    intTree1 = BinaryTree()
    for e in numbers:
        intTree1.insert(e)

    print("\nIs intTree1 full? ", end = "")
    print(intTree1.isFullBinaryTree())

    numbers2 = [2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7]
    intTree2 = BinaryTree()
    for e in numbers2:
        intTree2.insert(e)


    print("\nIs intTree2 full? ", end = "")
    print(intTree2.isFullBinaryTree())


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tree looked like  `/\`, then I think it would return True because you're only iterating the outside of the tree, not checking the fullness of the inner branches

Instead of looping at all, or even counting, I would suggest recursion

You'll need to implement the `isFullBinaryTree` methods on the TreeNode class for this to work, though.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.element = e
        self.left = None # Point to the left node, default None
        self.right = None # Point to the right node, default None

    def isFullBinaryTree(self):
        # check if we are a leaf 
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            return True 
        # recursively check the left fullness 
        full_left = self.left.isFullBinaryTree() if self.left else False 
        # recursively check the right fullness 
        full_right = self.right.isFullBinaryTree() if self.right else False
        # return True if checked that both left and right are full 
        return full_left and full_right
```

Once you do this, then the BinaryTree class can simply be checking if the root exists and if the root TreeNode is considered full itself.

e.g.

```
def isFullBinaryTree(self):
    return self.root.isFullBinaryTree() if self.root else False
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed the rightNode = current.left to rightNode = current.right. I do not know how to code the isFullBinaryTree methods on the TreeNode class as you suggested. I am looking for a way to only add code to the BinaryTree class without changing the TreeNode class. what would you suggest in that case?

Comment: And after that, are your tests passing anymore?

Comment: Sorry I edited to add to the above comment. But I think so? My problem is that I don't know what the tree looks like..

Comment: Well, assuming your insert method works, it shouldn't take too long to just draw out the tree yourself on paper

Comment: I don't think it is working. But, I don't think I know how to code what you suggested in the TreeNode..

Comment: You should know how. Given that you've already written functions for the BinaryTree class... Functions are functions, and can be put in any class